# How does this code find the number of trailing zeros from any base number factorial?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, number-theory

The code below works perfectly but I would like someone to explain to me the mathematics behind it.  Basically, how does it work?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>  /* atoi */

#define min(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   const int base = 16;
   int n,i,j,p,c,noz,k;

   n = 7;  /* 7! = decimal 5040 or 0x13B0  - 1 trailing zero */  
   noz = n;
   j = base;
   /* Why do we start from 2 */
   for (i=2; i <= base; i++)
   {
      if (j % i == 0)
      {   
         p = 0;  /* What is p? */
         while (j % i== 0)
         {
            p++;
            j /= i;
         }
         c = 0;
         k = n;
         /* What is the maths behind this while loop? */
         while (k/i > 0)
         {
            c += k/i;
            k /= i;
         }
         noz = min(noz, c/p);
      }
   }
   printf("%d! has %d trailing zeros\n", n, noz);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: why start from base 2? because `j % 1` will neer have a remainder.

Comment: @Marc B: Variable `p` counts the number of times that the value of variable `j` is divisible by the value of variable `i`, and it does so only for prime values of variable `i` (due to the `j /= i`). The loop starts from 2 because this is the smallest prime factor.

Comment: @MarcB That's not really a good explanation, since 1 is in fact a divisor, so why not consider it? The reason is that we only want prime divisors

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that the problem is equivalent to finding the highest power of *base* which divides *n!*.

If the base was prime (let's call it *p*), we could use a [theorem from number theory](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Multiplicity_of_Prime_Factor_in_Factorial) to compute the highest power of *p* that divides *n!*:

[image]

Let's extract the part of your code that does this into a function:

```
int maximum_power_of_p_in_fac(int p, int n) {
    int mu = 0;
    while (n/p > 0) {
        mu += n/p;
        n /= p;
    }
    return mu;
}
```

Now what happens if *base* is a prime power? Let's say we have *base = p<sup>q</sup>*. Then if *μ* is the highest power of *p* which divides *n!* and *r = floor(μ/q)*, we have

> (p^q)^r = p^(qr) divides p^μ divides n!

and

> (p^q)^(r+1) = p^(q(r+1)) >= p^(μ+1) does *not* divide n!

So *r* is the maximum power of *p^q* in n!. Let's write a function for that as well:

```
int maximum_power_of_pq_in_fac(int p, int q, int n) {
    return maximum_power_of_p_in_fac(p, n) / q;
}
```

So what if *base* is general number? Let's say

> base = p<sub>1</sub><sup>q<sub>1</sub></sup>  p<sub>2</sub><sup>q<sub>2</sub></sup> ...  p<sub>m</sub><sup>q<sub>m</sub></sup>

(this is the unique prime factorization of *base*). Then we just solve the problem for all p<sub>i</sub><sup>q<sub>i</sub></sup> and take the minimum of those:

```
int maximum_power_of_base_in_fac(int base, int n) {
    int res = infinity;
    for every factor p^q in the prime factorization in base:
       res = min(res, maximum_power_of_pq_in_fac(p,q,n));
    return res;
}
```

How to factorize *base*? Well we can just use trial division, like your example code does. We start by checking whether 2 is a prime factor. If it is, we compute `maximum_power_of_pq_in_fac` and divide *base* by 2 until it is no longer divisible by 2. Then we proceed with the next candidate factor:

```
void factorize(int base) {
    for (int p = 2; p <= base; ++p) {
        if (base % p == 0) { // if base is divisible by p, p is a prime factor
            int q = 0;
            while (base % p == 0) { // compute q and get rid of all the p factors
                q++;
                base /= p;
            }
            // do something with factor p^q
        }
        // proceed with next candidate divisor
    }
}
```

By examining the code carefully, you will find that it contains all the above elements, only put together in a single loop, which is a bit confusing.

**UPDATE:** In case you are interested, the algorithm you presented has complexity *O(base * log n)*. You can easily make it *O(sqrt(base) * log n)* by adapting the prime factorization routine slightly:

```
void factorize(int base) {
    for (int p = 2; p*p <= base; ++p) { // only check prime factors up to sqrt(base)
        // ... same as before
    }
    if (base) {
        // there is exactly one prime factor > sqrt(base). 
        // It certainly has multiplicity 1.

        // process prime factor base^1
    }   
}
```

And of course you can use any other more sophisticated prime factorization algorithm if you want to speed things up even more.

Comment: I think the code in the question does unnecessary things. We simply need to find the minimum of the highest power of 2 and the highest power of 5 in the factorial of the number to find the number of trailing zeros in the factorial.

Comment: @ajay The code works for general bases. Of course what you describe is exactly what that algorithm would do for `base = 10 = 2^1 * 5^1`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it finds prime factors of `base`, where `i` is prime and i<sup>p</sup> is a factor of base, and then figures out how many `i` factors will exist in n!, divides that by p, and tracks the minimum number of that result over all the prime factors of `base`.

So to answer the questions in the code:

1. why do we start from 2

   - because 2 is the smallest prime
2. what is p?

   - p is the 'power' for the prime factor i of the base (so i<sup>p</sup> is a factor of base)
3. What is the maths behind this loop

   - the loop is counting (`c`) the number of factors of `i` in `n!`