# Given x,y, How to find whether x! is divisible by y or not?

Tags: algorithm, performance

computing x! can be very costly and might often result in overflow. Is there a way to find out whether x! is divisible by y or not without computing x!?

- For y < x, its trivial;
- But,for y > x, e.g. x = 5 and y = 60; I am struggling to find a way without computing x!

Comment: How does `y` compare to `x`? If `y<=x` then `y` definitely divides `x!`. If `y` is prime and `y>x`, then it doesn't, but if `y>x` and all it's prime factors are `<=x`, then maybe... In that case, you might solve it by generating a list of all the factors of `2..x`, and then make sure that the factors of `y` are a subset of that list...

Comment: You can try asking on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is basically a math definitions/simple algorithm problem - mentioning "prime factorization" is almost too dangerous a hint because you could cheat by looking that up

Comment: @clwhisk That totally depends on the scale of the numbers x and y

Comment: @NiklasB. Totally? The difficulty of coding a solution scarcely seems to depend on the scale of x, and my comment wasn't directly related to the difficulty faced by the computer.

Comment: @clwhisk What I'm saying is that of course it is easy to write *any* algorithm that solves the problem, but not so easy to write one that actually works for larger numbers

Comment: @NiklasB. but finding the prime factorization of `y` more or less solves the problem, and also appears to be a minimum amount of work

Comment: @clwhisk Please describe how finding the factorization of `y` solves the problem trivially. I'm not so sure about that. Remember that `x!` will be much too large to be actually represented by machine words, even for values as low as 50. Sure there might be a simple O(x! + sqrt(y)) algorithm, but there is also a (super-exponentially much) better O(log x * log y + sqrt(y)) variant

Comment: @NiklasB. I didn't say trivially. Put your propaganda somewhere more legitimate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If x and y are really large, so that it's not viable to iterate through all the numbers 1 to x, you can instead just factorize y and compute for every prime factor whether its maximum power in y also divides x!.

I've written about the algorithm more detailled [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202489/how-does-this-code-find-the-number-of-trailing-zeros-from-any-base-number-factor/23202920#23202920).

Basically the check goes like this:

```cpp
// computes maximum q so that p^q divides n!
bool max_power_of_p_in_fac(int p, int n) { 
    int mu = 0;
    while (n/p > 0) {
        mu += n/p;
        n /= p;
    }
    return mu;
}
// checks whether y divides x!
bool y_divides_x_fac(int y, int x) {
    for each prime factor p^q of y:
        if (max_power_of_p_in_fac(p, x) < q)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

This results in an algorithm for the case x < y of complexity  O(time to factorize y + log x * #number of prime factors of y).

Obviously y can have at O(log y) prime factors. So with [Pollard's rho factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard's_rho_algorithm) this would be something like O(y^(1/4) + log x * log y)

The correctness can be proven using [this theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Multiplicity_of_Prime_Factor_in_Factorial):

[image]

Comment: that's interesting! O(sqrt(y)*log(x))

Comment: @Ralor Actually more like O(log log y * log x + y^(1/4)) or something, depending on the implementation of the factorizing algorithm

Comment: count of prime factors ~ log log y ?

Comment: @Ralor It should be "number of distinct prime factors". log log y is just a rough estimate, but primorials [grow very fast](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239523/how-to-show-how-primorials-grow-asymptotically).

Comment: @Ralor Actually log log y was wrong, I think it's more like log y

Comment: @Nicklas B. hmm, ok. I used the fact that O(sqrt(y)) factorizing algorithm will find prime numbers on all odd numbers <= sqrt(y), so my upper bound may be not so good. log(y) is better of course.

Comment: @NiklasB. acc to your algo, if x=5,y=60; prime factors of y = 5,3,2; and x is not divisible by 3 so it says 5! is not divisible by 60. Am i misinterpreting something here?

Comment: @RiteshMahato x! is disivible by 3 though. I had a typo in the answer, please check again

Comment: @NiklasB. what is 'n' in your function 'pq_divides_x_fac'?

Comment: @RiteshMahato Sorry, there were some more mistakes while renaming variables to match your scenario. Now I just use the function from my other answer, so if you're invited to have a look at my explanation there as well. Although the theorem that the correctness based on can also be found in this answer :)

Answer (score 7):

Compute the [prime factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factorization) of `x!` and `y`.  You can do this without computing `x!` by factorizing every number from `2` to `x` and collecting all of the factors together. If the factors of `y` is a subset of the factors of `x!` then it is divisible.

Comment: Actually you don't even need to factorize x!. Suppose I want to know if 2^17 divides 20!. I know that 2, 4, 6, 8... each contribute a 2 to the prime factorization. Then 4, 8, 12, 16 each contribute another, and so on, for a total of 2^(20/2 + 20/4 + 20/8 + 20/16) = 2^18. Similarly it has 3^(20/3 + 20/9) = 3^8 as factors.

Comment: For the given example, the prime factorization of 60 is 2^2 * 3 * 5. The prime factorization of 5! has 2^(5/2 + 5/4) = 2^3, so that factor checks out. It also has 3^(5/3) = 3^1 and 5^(5/5) = 5^1.

Comment: O(x^1.5 + y^1.5 + sqrt(x)log(x) + sqrt(y)log(y)) using NlogN sorting and linear set intersection

Answer (score 2):

For every `i` from `1` to `x`, update `y /= gcd(y, i)`. The divisibility check at the end is `y == 1`.

Comment: that's interesting! O(xlog(y))